# Advantage of using new Integer(a) over a

Tags: java

Say that I have some code

```
public List<Integer> cardIndexes() {
        List<Integer> selected = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int k = 0; k < cards.length; k++) {
            if (cards[k] != null) {
                selected.add(new Integer(k));
            }
        }
        return selected;
    }
```

in which it fills up a list named selected with a bunch of integers, if that point in the card index does not equal null. I am just wondering if there is any advantage to using `selected.add(new Integer(k));`, over just using `selected.add(k);`. I assume that the advantage gained here is that you can call methods to modify k directly on k, instead of having to use `new Integer(k).someMethod;`, but is this the only advantage gained here?

Comment: `k` cannot be "null" anyway here; and what the Java compiler will do for boxing is call `Integer.valueOf()`, not `new Integer()`. There is not a question of advantage or disadvantage: you just cannot have a `Collection` of primitive types in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Java 5, there's autoboxing that will automatically create an instance of the object wrapper class from a primitive variable. In short, no, there's no advantage.

Comment: To be more precise: create an instance *or reuse an instance from a cache*.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov that's valid for `Integer`, AFAIK `Float` and `Double` don't have cache.

Answer (score 1):

The only "advantage" (if you'd like to call it so) would be that `new Integer(a)` makes Java's autoboxing explicitly visible.

This is not an issue in your case, but there are cases that might get confusing, especially when you're mixing classes with primitives (there is a reason why Eclipse can mark autoboxing conversions as error/warning).

On the opposite, autoboxing will result in `Integer.valueOf(a)` in the byte code, which is usually to be preferred over `new Integer(a)` for reasons of memory consumption and performance (cf. [the official javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-int-)):

> public static Integer valueOf(int i)
>
> Returns an Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a
>   new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be
>   used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as this method is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>   caching frequently requested values. This method will always cache
>   values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values
>   outside of this range.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can simply do:

```
selected.add(k);
```

because auto-boxing will create an `Integer` object anyway to add to the `List<Integer>`.

> I assume that the advantage gained here is that you can call methods to modify k directly on k, instead of having to use new Integer(k).someMethod

No, `Integer` is immutable, (like all primitive wrapper classes). These classes are wrapper for the primitive types, mainly for use in collections as standard objects and provides utility functions (e.g. conversion between types).

But if you mind about performances (if you have arithmetics on big lists), you should be aware of boxing/unboxing and when to use `int[]` versus `ArrayList<Integer>`.